# Problem with accessing xml node value in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmldocument

I have written the following asp.net code ,How to access the value of minvalue from color node and bgcolor from chart node ?

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
string xmlFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Data/Example.xml");
doc.Load(xmlFile);
XmlNodeList xmlnode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("value");
```

My XML looks like this:

```
<Chart editMode='1' bgColor='FFFFFF' bgAlpha='0' showBorder='0' upperLimit='1000' >
   <colorRange> 
      <color minValue='0' maxValue='100' code='F6BD0F' />
   </colorRange>
   <value>665</value>
</Chart>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
        XmlNode chartNode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Chart")[0];
        XmlNode colorNode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Chart")[0].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0];

        string minvalue = colorNode.Attributes["minValue"].Value;
        string bgColor = chartNode.Attributes["bgColor"].Value;
```

EDIT: This code should now work, but it would probably be easier to use one of the XPath suggestions posted

Comment: I am getting the following error 'System.Xml.XmlNode' does not contain a definition for 'GetElementsByTagName' and no extension method 'GetElementsByTagName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.XmlNode' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @mahesh, sorry - I have edited that code and it should now work

Comment: The best overloaded method match for System.Xml.XmlNodeList.this[int] has some invalid arguments

Comment: @mahesh, OK, fixed and compile tested

Answer (score 2):

Just use the XPath:

```
var minValue = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Chart/colorRange/color/@minValue").Value;
```

Comment: but he he is not looking for the minValue attribute's value.

Answer (score 1):

you can go here and paste your XML fragment:

[Online XPath Tester](http://www.mizar.dk/XPath/Default.aspx)

then you will realize that you can select your value with an XPATH like this, for example:

```
//Chart/Value
```

Comment: Thanks for the very usefull reply,Can i access that minValue through following code?    var minValue = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Chart/colorRange/color/@minValue").Value;

Comment: test it in the online tester and you will find this out ;-) here: http://www.mizar.dk/XPath/Default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use XDocument class from System.Xml.Linq and you will be able to do it like this:

```
var minValue=doc.Root.Element("colorRange").Element("color").Attribute("minValue").Value;

var bgColor = doc.Root.Attribute("bgColor").Value;
```

Comment: he is looking for the content of the Value node, he wants to extract 665

Comment: It is not a problem - doc.Root.Element("value").Value.
Have you read his question? 
"How to access the value of minvalue from color node and bgcolor from chart node ?"

Comment: you are right, I was misguided by his code: XmlNodeList xmlnode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("value"); which does not look at all at minValue. Sorry about that